# Meteor Collection insert doesn't work inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have collection insert inside API callback function, callback works but collection doesn't insert value. Here is code:

```
namecheapApi.apiCall("namecheap.domains.check", {DomainList: 'example.com'}).then(function (data) {
                console.log("Inside callback");
                Domain.insert({somefield: 2}));       
         });
```

If make call just insert:

```
Domain.insert({somefield: 2}));
```

value is inserted so problem is not in Collection definition. Code is running on server. What can be the reason ?

Comment: When you make the insert call `Domain.insert({somefield: 2}));` that is working, are you running it client or server-side?

Comment: aren't you getting an error saying something like "Meteor code must be run in a fiber?"

Comment: Are you sure the apiCall is returning a fulfilled promise?

Comment: I'm runnung it server side.There are no any error messages. I'm sure apiCall is returning filfilled promose as I have console log message.